# How do I write a program to XK-1A xmos controller flash?

Tags: embedded, xmos

Reading through the information on the XK-1A Hardware Manual it states that I can write software to the flash memory so I don't have to program from my computer each time I power it on.  However I can't figure out how to do this.  How can I write programs to the flash memory on my XK-1A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier than I thought and is not included in the instructions because it is very easy.

When programming using the xTIMEcomposer simply go to Run -> Flash Configurations then setup a new flash configuration for the current project and flash.  It's that easy and you now have your program written in flash.

Comment: there is a command line flash tool in their toolchain as well that works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I used command prompt to program flash like this:

```
# check connection of XTAG and target board
xflash -l
# program flash
xflash project_bin.xb(or xe)
```

But first of all, you shoud have an xn file at the same folder of xb file, this xn file should confirgure all flash ic parameters of your project.

You can also use command line to creat a flash image for mass production either which is not your question anyway.